# FindFirst Syntax Error with date criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax-error, findfirst

I have following lines in VBA Access, but I receive Syntax Error by FindFirst and I don't understand why.

```
criteria = "[HolidayDate] = " & "#" & myDate & "#"
rst.FindFirst (criteria)
If rst.NoMatch Then
    count = count + 1
End If
```

Comment: Yes, HolidayDate is a Date-Type Field in "Holiday"-Table

Comment: mydate = CDate("01.0" & Int(Me.cboMonth) & "." & Int(Me.cboYear))

Comment: the purpose is to count the workdays in a month

Comment: I have found an another solution

Comment: The problem was probably the brackets. Remove them: rst.FindFirst criteria

Answer (score 0):

```
Do While mydate <= EndOfMonth
        If Weekday(mydate, vbMonday) < 6 Then
             With rst
                .MoveFirst
                flag = False
                Do While Not .EOF
                    If CDate(.Fields("HolidayDate").Value) = myDate Then
                        flag = True
                    End If
                .MoveNext
                Loop
                If flag = False Then
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            End With
        End If
        myDate = myDate + 1
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping through a recordset is not the solution.

If *HolidayDate* really is of data type DateTime, this will work:

```vb
criteria = "[HolidayDate] = #" & Format(myDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
rst.FindFirst criteria
```

If not, something else is going on.